# Не могу несколько полей соединить в 1 запрос к API OPEN AI LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, api, chatgpt, chatgpt-api

Всем привет!
Попытаюсь кратко и понятно объяснить
У меня есть страница чата :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('main')
<section>
    <div class="container py-5">
  
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-15">
          
          <div class="card mt-2" style="border-radius: 15px;">
          <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-3 text-white border-bottom-0" style="border-top-left-radius: 15px; border-top-right-radius: 15px; background-color:#47b2e4">
       <h3 class="text-center">DOCUMENTATOR</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="p-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                  <option value="1">One</option>
                  <option value="2">Two</option>
                  <option value="3">Three</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                  <option value="1">One</option>
                  <option value="2">Two</option>
                  <option value="3">Three</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                  <option value="1">One</option>
                  <option value="2">Two</option>
                  <option value="3">Three</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                  <option value="1">One</option>
                  <option value="2">Two</option>
                  <option value="3">Three</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                  <option value="1">One</option>
                  <option value="2">Two</option>
                  <option value="3">Three</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          
            <div class="card-body">
              <div id="chat-box" style="height: 280px" class="overflow-auto p-3"></div>
              <div class="form-outline">
                <form id="ask-chatgpt-form">
                  @csrf
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="prompt" placeholder="Type your question..."></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" style="background-color:#47b2e4"
                    class="btn text-white float-right"><i class="bi bi-send-fill"></i></button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  
  <template id="user-message-box-template">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end mb-4">
      <div class="p-3 me-3 border" style="border-radius: 15px; background-color: #fbfbfb;">
        <p class="small mb-0" id="message-box-text"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <template id="chatgpt-message-box-template">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start mb-4">
      <div class="p-3 ms-3" style="border-radius: 15px; background-color: rgba(0, 166, 126,.2);">
        <p class="small mb-0" id="message-box-text"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#submit-btn", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $("#ask-chatgpt-form");
  var formData = form.serialize();
  var textarea = form.find('textarea[name="prompt"]');
  generateChatBoxMessage(false, textarea.val());
  textarea.val('');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'chatgpt/ask',
    data: formData,
    success: function(answer) {
      generateChatBoxMessage(true, answer);
    },
  });
});

function generateChatBoxMessage(isChatGPTMessage, messageText) {
  var template = isChatGPTMessage ? $("#chatgpt-message-box-template").html() : $("#user-message-box-template").html();
  var messageBox = $(template);
  messageBox.find('#message-box-text').text(messageText);
  $('#chat-box').append(messageBox);
}
</script>

@endsection
```

А также код контроллера chatController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class chatController extends Controller
{
    public function messeges(Request $request)
    {
        $prompt = $request->input('prompt');
        return $this->askToChatGPT($prompt);
    }

    private function askToChatGPT($prompt) 
    {
        $response = Http::withoutVerifying()
            ->withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('openai.api_key'),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ])->post('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', [
                "model" => "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                "messages" => [[
                    "role" => "user",
                    "content" => $prompt
                ]],
                "max_tokens" => 1000
            ]);

        return $response->json()['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
    }
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы в форме выбранные селлекторы и данные написанные в форме отправлялись на сервер как единый запрос. Например Ввели запрос в текстовое поле "опиши текст на языке" а в селекторе выбрали "Английский", теперь к API должно отправиться 1 сообщение "опиши текст на языке Английский"

Answer (score 0):

Просто считайте значения из инпутов и объедините их в единую строку. Например так. Можно делать листенер на кнопку как у вас, можно на форму как внизу. Это сути не меняет

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const prompt = `${e.target.elements.text.value} ${e.target.elements.language.value}`
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('prompt', prompt)
  
  /*
    $.ajax(....)
  */
  
  console.log(prompt)
})
```

```html
<form id="form">

<input type="text" name="text" />
<select name="language">
  <option>Английский</option>
  <option>Французский</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```